# How to grep SQL Server stored procedures?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, powershell, grep

I would like to run a standard [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep) over all stored procedures in a given SQL Server database (assume 2005 or later). I have found a variety of simple queries to list the names of stored procedures containing a specific object, e.g.

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%table_I_want_to_find%'
```

But what I really want is, like grep, to list the specific lines in the identified stored procedures (so I do not have to manually open each one and see if it is what I am looking for).

I am open to solutions in T-SQL or PowerShell, or even an off-the-shelf utility.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544134/ways-to-search-for-a-pattern-in-all-stored-procedures-and-then-open-it-to-be-alt)'s a stored procedure solution called sp_grep.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [SQL Search from Red Gate](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-search/). It's a free tool and is fantastic.

Comment: +1 seconded - great tool, and ***FREE***, too! Indispensable!

Comment: I agree, Icarus. I had completely forgotten about Red Gate's excellent tool--that does just what I need.

Answer (score 3):

I am brand new to SQL Server, but the following seems to work great and has proved itself to be quite useful already.  I am using SQL Server 2008.

```
select ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE, ROUTINE_BODY, ROUTINE_DEFINITION
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
where ROUTINE_DEFINITION like '%searchtext%'
order by ROUTINE_SCHEMA, ROUTINE_NAME, ROUTINE_TYPE, ROUTINE_DEFINITION;
```

For completeness, here are some similar queries you'll probably want to know about:

```
exec sp_help 'myTable'

select name
from sys.all_views
order by name;

select TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
order by TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, TABLE_TYPE;

select TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, DATA_TYPE
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where COLUMN_NAME = 'myColumn'
order by TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, COLUMN_NAME;
```

Comment: Bad idea, ROUTINE_DEFINITION  is a varchar(8000). If your stored procedure is longer than 8000 characters, it won't fine references past the 8000 limit. Happened to me... Instead, use object_definition(object_id) from sys.whatever, which has varchar(max)

Comment: 1) The first solution finds the procedures containing the search string ok.
2) Then paste all the ROUTINE_DEFINITIONs into notepad++ which is free
3) Ctrl-F to search and "Find All in Current Document" gives lines with numbers.
4) Double click a line to go there
5) Search backwards for the Proc name.
Heed Stefan's warning.

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/544134/ways-to-search-for-a-pattern-in-all-stored-procedures-and-then-open-it-to-be-alt)'s a stored procedure solution called sp_grep.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [SMO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx) to dump the stored procedure DDL to files, and then use grep on them.

There are some examples of extracting the DDL [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162153.aspx) (called Scripting).